# How do I get WorkFlowActivityBase class in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, dynamics-crm, crm

I am creating a custom workflow in Microsoft Dynamics CRM to automatically update a field when a record is saved.

A developer on a forum provided the following source code; but he is not responding to my questions.

```
public class SalesRepActivity2 : WorkFlowActivityBase
{
    [Input("Sales Rep Name")]
    public InArgument<string> SalesRepName { get; set; }

    [Output("Sales Rep")]
    [ReferenceTarget("systemuser")]
    public OutArgument<EntityReference> SalesRep { get; set; }

    [Output("IsSuccess")]
    public OutArgument<bool> IsSuccess { get; set; }

    [Output("Message")]
    public OutArgument<string> Message { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(
        CodeActivityContext activityContext,
        IWorkflowContext workflowContext,
        IOrganizationService CrmService,
        ITracingService trace)
    {
        try
        {
            string salesRepName = SalesRepName.Get(activityContext);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(salesRepName))
            {
                IsSuccess.Set(activityContext, false);
                Message.Set(activityContext, "Sales Rep Name not provided");
            }


            var QEsystemuser = new QueryExpression("systemuser");
            QEsystemuser.ColumnSet.AddColumns("salesrepname");
            QEsystemuser.Criteria.AddCondition("salesrepname", ConditionOperator.Equal, salesRepName);

            var results = CrmService.RetrieveMultiple(QEsystemuser);

            if (results == null || !results.Entities.Any())
            {
                IsSuccess.Set(activityContext, false);
                Message.Set(activityContext, "User with " + salesRepName + " not found");
                return;
            }

            if (results.Entities.Count > 1)
            {
                IsSuccess.Set(activityContext, false);
                Message.Set(activityContext, "Multiple users found with same name : " + salesRepName);
                return;
            }


            IsSuccess.Set(activityContext, true);
            SalesRep.Set(activityContext, results.Entities.Single().ToEntityReference());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IsSuccess.Set(activityContext, false);
            Message.Set(activityContext, "An error occurred trying to find user : " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I am trying to get the code to compile on my machine.

I installed the following NuGet packages, which resolved most of the errors:
  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow.2015
  Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.2015

But my project cannot resolve the WorkFlowActivityBase class.

Is there a reference I should set or a NuGet package I should install to resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`WorkFlowActivityBase` is a custom base class that implements the `CodeActivity` (System.Activities) anyone can write, it's not an official Dynamics class. Yon can find dozen of classes lie that in the web.
Basically, you should use the `CodeActivity`. here as an example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/workflow/sample-create-custom-workflow-activity

Comment: I tried using CodeActivity instead, but in that case I'll need CrmService for the following:
var results = CrmService.RetrieveMultiple(QEsystemuser);

How can I get access to CrmService?

Comment: The CrmService object in the code you are referencing is an object that implements IOrganizationService. Take a look at the documentation I linked in my answer, specifically the "Get Contextual information" and "Use the Organization Service" sections

Comment: It looks like Ziv also added a second answer providing sample of such an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not a good place for you to start because it makes heavy use of proprietary objects. Ziv has provided good information about extending the CodeActivity class but I do not recommend starting there. Instead read about how to develop custom workflow activities, and write a workflow using the base Microsoft classes so that you understand how they work:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/workflow/workflow-extensions

Once you have some experience with creating custom workflows, and you understand the limitations of the base objects, then go back and implement something more fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Here in an exaple from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/workflow/sample-create-custom-workflow-activity):

```
namespace Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples
{
    public sealed class SimpleSdkActivity : CodeActivity
    {
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            //Create the tracing service
            ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

            //Create the context
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
           ...
           var systemUsers = service.RetrieveMultiple(QEsystemuser)
       }
   }
}
```